# Context is null in Data Access Layer when using n-tier architecture in Web API, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I'm trying to create a Web API. I'm using Entity Framework here, code first approach.

This is a n-tier architecture. Meaning, I have created multiple projects in a single solution as shown below.

[image]

I have a controller method which is a get method. I will pass userid as the parameter.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BankController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBankApplicationDAL _bankAPI;

    public BankController(IBankApplicationDAL bankAPI)
    {
        _bankAPI = bankAPI;
    }

    [HttpGet("{userId}")]
    public IActionResult GetAccountDetailsId(int userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var values = _bankAPI.GetAccountDetailsId(userId);
            return Ok(values);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

In the DAL layer, this is what I have:

```
using BankApplicationAPI.Model;
using BankApplicationAPI.Data;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace BankApplicationAPI.DAL
{
    public class BankApplicationDAL : IBankApplicationDAL
    {
        DataContext context;

        public AccountDetails GetAccountDetailsId(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                var values = context.AccountDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId); // context is null here.
                return values;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `DataContext` I have:

```
namespace BankApplicationAPI.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<AccountDetails> AccountDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransactionDetails> TransactionDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run this application, I get an exception saying context is null in DAL method (where I have put comment).

How do I create an object for `DataContext`? Can anyone help me here? It's very important. Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = @"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=AppDB;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";

    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connection));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddSingleton<IBankApplicationDAL, BankApplicationDAL>();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your `BankApplicationDAL` class. You never assign a value to your private `context` field, so it is `null` by default. What do you expect?

Comment: @vasily.sib , yes I have not assigned a value to context field. How do I assign value is my question. If you can help me in that, it would be grateful.

Comment: @hassan.ef posted a correct answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use this changing:

```
 public class BankApplicationDAL : IBankApplicationDAL
 {
            DataContext _context;
            public BankApplicationDAL(DataContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }

            public AccountDetails GetAccountDetailsId(int userId)
            {
                try
                {
                    var values = context.AccountDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId); // context is null here.
                    return values;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have tried what you have given. I'm getting this exception: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'BankApplicationAPI.Data.DataContext' from singleton 'BankApplicationAPI.DAL.IBankApplicationDAL'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)

Comment: do you add BankApplicationDAL  and IBankApplicationDAL in startup?

Comment: I added startup.cs for your reference. Am I missing something in that?

Comment: Look, your `DataContext` is **scoped**, which means that for every request there will be new instance of `DataContext`. Your `IBankApplicationDAL` is **singleton**, which means that it will be created only once. Can you see this now? On any requests (except the first one) your `IBankApplicationDAL` instance will hold outdated instance of `DataContext`. This is exactly what exeption message is telling you.

Comment: So should I add singleton object for DataContext also ?

Comment: @CrazyCoder no, make `IBankApplicationDAL` scoped instead

Comment: @vasily.sib, I don't quite understand ,what do you mean by scoped? Can you give me any example please. My apologies, if it is a very basic question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it's ok. Scoped dependency means that it will be created for the scope of the request (each request will have his own instance of this scoped dependency). Just replace `services.AddSingleton<IBankApplicationDAL, BankApplicationDAL>();` with `services.AddScoped<IBankApplicationDAL, BankApplicationDAL>();`